# sed regex : remove occurrences of [ and ] from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am using Linux Mint 17.

I am able to replace everything from the test string except `[` and `]` (opening and closing square brackets).

Here is my expression, which is within a bash script, which I run from the command line

```
video_title=$(echo $video_title | sed 's|[?![]]||g')
```

I have tried placing \ before both square brackets and this does not work. 
If I remove the `[` and the `]` the expression replaces the `?` and the `!` just fine.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: it is always helpful to have some sample input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual, to include `]` in the list, it needs to be the first character.

```
 A leading `^' reverses the meaning of LIST, so that it matches any
 single character _not_ in LIST.  To include `]' in the list, make
 it the first character (after the `^' if needed), to include `-'
 in the list, make it the first or last; to include `^' put it
 after the first character.
```

So try something like this:

```
$ echo '[!2015?]' | sed 's|[][?!]||g'
2015
```

Answer (score 1):

For just deleting characters from the input `tr` is a more appropriate tool than `sed`. In your case you can just use

```
video_title=$(echo $video_title | tr -d '?![]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
$ echo 'foo?![bar]' | sed 's~[?!]\|\]\|\[~~g'
foobar
```